# OpenPose in Google Collab to be Permanent to my google drive?

Tags: google-colaboratory, permanent, openpose, permanent-generation

Every time i use :
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VDjRLKAu9KLQky0gv4RLJjeH6NRPiWXy?usp=sharing
i have to wait about 35 min installing the openpose
is there anway installing it permanent and avoid waiting installtion time everytime i use the openpose ?
i have checked the answer here : [Permanent Installation of OpenPose in Google Collab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342255/permanent-installation-of-openpose-in-google-collab)
and couldn't apply it to my colab.